# Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'. No idea what is going on

Tags: c#, indexing, apply

So i'm trying to read a txt file in string theMap and then make a copy of theMap in map and return map. Also im trying to read the Txt file in 2d string. Then the returned array which is map. I want to print it at the console and there is the "Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type 'method group'" problem here is the code also.

```
    public static string[,] Reader()
    {
        string theMap = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\Public\Console Slayer\Map\map.txt");


        int k = 0, l = 0;
        string[,] map = new string[11,54];
        foreach (var row in theMap.Split('\n'))
        {
            foreach (var col in row.Trim().Split(' '))
            {
                map[l,k] = (col.Trim());
                l++;
            }
            k++;
        }
        return map;
    }
    public static void Printer()
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < 54; x++)
            {
                Console.Write(Reader[y,x]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
    }
    static void Main()
    {
        Reader();
        Printer();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Reader` is a method.  You cannot index it, but you can index the *result* of it:

```
Console.Write(Reader()[y,x]);
//                  ^ You need these parens to invoke the method.
```

However, this will invoke the function for every loop, reading the file in 11 * 54 = 594 times!  Read the file once and store the result instead; there is no need to call this method on each loop iteration:

```
var data = Reader();

for (int y = 0; y < 11; y++)
{
    for (int x = 0; x < 54; x++)
    {
        Console.Write(data[y,x]);
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

Comment: The OP probably doesn't meant to call `Reader()` 594 times though.

Comment: @T.C. Yes, was working on adding that to the answer before you said this.  :)

Comment: @nightxx You never reset `l` to zero in your reader, so it will grow beyond 10. Presumably you need `l = 0` prior to your `foreach (var col ...` loop.  But note that this is a very fragile reader function; malformed input will crash the program.